# Firebase realtime database - read the latest item under multiple child objects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write the Firebase realtime database ValueEventListener for the following dataset. I've gone thru the documentation but couldn't the figure out way to read the data for the following scenario i.e latest message under every person object. Seems we can use orderByValue() and limitToFirst() to get the latest message under a specific child (person object), but here I'm trying to read the latest messages under multiple child objects.

**Dataset:**

```
{
    "messages":{
        "person-1":{
            "shdjkashdjash":
                {
                    "message": "Hi",
                    "date": 1544061643815
                },
            "ashakjshasasjhda":
                {
                    "message": "Hello",
                    "date":1544061724422
                }
        },
        "person-2":{
            "ahsgfasgfhagf":
                {
                    "message": "How are you",
                    "date": 1544061773193
                },
            "sfjksfsaflashf":
                {
                    "message": "Hey",
                    "date":1544061777661
                }
        },
        "person-3":{
            "fashfahfahf":
                {
                    "message": "This is the sample example",
                    "date": 1544061784096
                },
            "sdfsfhshfsjhfshf":
                {
                    "message": "Firebase messages",
                    "date":1544061789927
                }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share your listener code to look into that?

Comment: ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // ...
  });
});

Comment: It's not possible with Realtime Database to have a single query that spans children from multiple locations like this.  You'll need to query each location separately.

Comment: @DougStevenson any performance issues if we have multiple Firebase realtime database Child event listeners in the same app?

Comment: No, listeners on small amounts of data are cheap.